# Rails http_basic_authenticate_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, passwords

Just had a newbie question regarding http_basic_authenticate_with. If I'm placing in my controller something simplistic as,

```
http_basic_authenticate_with :name => "user", :password => "secret"
```

how can I make sure that the password is secured. I just want to be able to place an app in production/publish it and have the entire app password protected in a secure manner.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can suggest to put password in environment.
For example you can do http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/set-environment-variable-linux/ 
export APP_USER='secret_user'
export APP_PASSWORD='secret_password'

```
# then in controller
http_basic_authenticate_with :name => ENV['secret_user'], :password => ENV['secret_password']
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the correct answer has been chosen; I like to add other options.

**Scenario:** Lets say you are creating a blog and want to have simple authentication. In your `post_controller.rb` you would add the following:

```
http_basic_authenticate_with name: ENV["BLOG_USERNAME"],password: ENV["BLOG_PASSWORD"],except: [:show]
```

In order to communicate with these variables 'securely', choose an option:

1. **Option 1**

   - Create `application.yml` file inside `config` folder; where you would add your configuration (username and password), for example:

     ```
     BLOG_USERNAME: "admin"
     BLOG_PASSWORD: "12345"
     ```
   - Now, since `application.yml` includes sensitive information, we want Git to ignore that file. Therefore add the following to `.gitignore` file: `/config/application.yml`
   - Now we need to load these variables by adding the following line to `application.rb` file:

     ```
     ENV.update YAML.load(File.read(File.expand_path('../application.yml', __FILE__)))
     ```
2. **Option 2** Use [Figaro gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro)

   - In your `Gemfile` add `gem "figaro"`, run `bundle install` and also run`figaro install`.
     Figaro will create `config/application.yml` file and adds it to your `.gitignore`.
   - Now add your own configuration to this file similar to step 1 above also follow step 3 and you're done!
     Check [Figaro's documentation](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro/tree/0-stable#readme) for more details.